# Sequence of number of vertices in a graph

Tags: graph

I want to generate a sequence of the number of vertices in all graphs which each edge has the same number of leaving edges. I dont have to generate the whole sequence. Let's say the first 50 if exists.

I want:

**Input**: the number of edges leaving each vertex
**Output**: a sequence of the number of vertices

So far, I have looked at complete graphs. Complete graphs with n vertices always have n-1 edges leaving each vertex. But there are other kinds　of graphs that have this property. For example, some polyhedrons, such as [snub dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron) and [truncated icosidodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosidodecahedron) have this property.

How should I approach my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean regular graphs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularGraph.html

I made a regular graph generator which isn't flawless by the way:
once you generate the nodes, say from 1 to n. You want regularity r.

For node 1, make connections to the following nodes until you reach degree r for node 1.
For node 2 you already have degree 1 (because of node 1), you connect again to further nodes until you reach degree r for node 2 too. And this way till the last node.
The flaw is that you can't define an r-regular graph for any number of nodes. The algorithm mentioned doesn't detect that, so some errors may occur. Also, this isn't a random r-regular graph generator, but instead give one possible solution.

I'm not much of an explainer, so please ask if the description lacks somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. I should be able to figure things out from the information you gave to me. Thanks again.